# Devise + auditable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i use Auditable's gem for model changes tracking.

On a controller, befor record save (for example), i can add a comment using:

```
user = User.new
user.name = "Bla bla"
user.audit_comment = "The user is created"
user.save
```

How can i do the same thing on Devise session?

When a user logs in, the field "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", etc.. are updated. How can i add the comment before record updates?

I have generated the devise controller, but i need to intercept the record update process

Comment: If you are trying to add a custom field to devise, follow - http://www.peoplecancode.com/tutorials/adding-custom-fields-to-devise. If you are trying to update your db before a record is created, use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)